# Use variables inside String.replace method regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using regex to replace some text inside my code like this :

```
text.replace(
    /\{\#(variable)\#\}/g,
    this.options.vars[i].companyName,
);
```

I want to use a variable inside the pattern because I have a string like this `lorem ipsum {#variable1#} dolor {#variable2#}`, but I can't find a way to pass a variable inside the pattern.

Comment: seek the documentation for `new RegExp()`

Comment: @JaromandaX I can't find it how to merge the pattern with outside variables

Comment: `new RegExp(\`\\{\\#(${variable})\\#\\}\`, 'g')` - don't forget ... to get a backslash `'\\'` in a string you need two ... alternative `new RegExp('\\{\\#('+variable+')\\#\\}', 'g')`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you so much, you saved my day